# Pinning a DLL in memory (increase reference count)

Tags: debugging, dll, memory-leaks, windbg, access-violation

I am trying to run an application, but the application exits due to an access violation. Running the application in the debugger I can see that this is caused by an unloaded library. I can not wait for the next release of the application, so I'm trying to workaround the problem.

I wonder whether WinDbg provides a way of increasing the reference count of a loaded module, similar to the C++ LoadLibrary() call. I could then break on module loads and increase the reference count on the affected DLL to see if I can use the application then.

I have already looked for commands starting with `.load`, `!load`, `.lock`, `!lock`, `.mod` and `!mod` in WinDbg help. .load will load the DLL as an extension into the debugger process, not into the target process.

**Update**

Forgot to mention that I have no source code, so I can't simply implement a LoadLibrary() call as a workaround and recompile.

The comment by Hans Passant leads me to `.call` and I tried to use it like

```
.call /v kernel32!LoadLibraryA("....dll")
```

but it gives the error message

> Symbol not a function in '.call /v kernel32!LoadLibraryA("....dll")'

**Update 2**

Probably the string for the file name in `.call` should be a pointer to some memory in the target process instead of a string which resides in WinDbg.exe where I type the command. That again means I would probably mean to allocate some memory to store the string inside, so this might become more complex.

Comment: Hard to guess why you want to do this, you would *hide* the bug.  Either debug it by setting a breakpoint on FreeLibrary() or bypass the bug by calling LoadLibrary() yourself so you'll increase the count.

Comment: To allocate the memory in the target use `.dvalloc` and the use `eza` to write an null terminated ascii string to the allocated address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `.call` in windbg as always been finicky to me. I believe you are having trouble with it because `kernel32` only has public symbols so the debugger doesn't know what it's arguments look like.

So let's look at some alternatives...

## The easy way

You can go grab a tool like [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), which I think is a wonderful addition to any debugger's tool chest. It has an option to inject a DLL into a process.

[image: Process Hacker Inject Dll]

Behind the scenes, it calls `CreateRemoteThread` to spawn a thread in the target process which calls `LoadLibrary` on the chosen DLL. With any luck, this will increase the module reference count. You can verify that the `LoadCount` has been increased in windbg by running the `!dlls` command before and after the dll injection.

## The hard way

You can also dig into the internal data structures Windows uses to keep track of a process's loaded modules and play with the `LoadCount`. This changes between versions of Windows and is a serious no-no. But, we're debugging, so, what the hell? ***Let's do this.***

Start by getting a list of loaded modules with `!dlls`. Suppose we care about `your.dll`; we might see something like:

```
0x002772a8: C:\path\to\your.dll
      Base   0x06b80000  EntryPoint  0x06b81000  Size        0x000cb000    DdagNode     0x002b3a10
      Flags  0x800822cc  TlsIndex    0x00000000  LoadCount   0x00000001    NodeRefCount 0x00000001
```

We can see that the load count is currently 1. To modify it, we could use the address printed before the module path. It is the address of the the `ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` the process holds for that module.

```
r? @$t0 = (ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY*) 0x002772a8
```

And, now you can change the LoadCount member to something larger as so:

```
?? @$t0->LoadCount = 2
```

But, as I said, this stuff changes with new versions of Windows. On Windows 8, the `LoadCount` member was moved out of `_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY` and into a new `ntdll!_LDR_DDAG_NODE` structure. In place of it, there is now an `ObsoleteNodeCount` which is not what we want.

On Windows 8, we would run the following command instead:

```
?? @$t0->DdagNode->LoadCount = 2
```

And, time to check our work...

```
0x002772a8: C:\path\to\your.dll
      Base   0x06b80000  EntryPoint  0x06b81000  Size        0x000cb000    DdagNode     0x002b3a10
      Flags  0x800822cc  TlsIndex    0x00000000  LoadCount   0x00000002    NodeRefCount 0x00000001
```

Awesome. It's 2 now. That'll teach `FreeLibrary` a lesson about unloading our DLLs before we say it can.

## The takeaway

Try the easy way first. If that doesn't work, you can start looking at the internal data structures Windows uses to keep track of this kind of stuff. I don't provide the hard way hoping you'll actually try it, but that it might make you more comfortable around the `!dlls` command and those data structures in the future.

Still, all modifying the `LoadCount` will afford you is confirmation that you are seeing a DLL get unloaded before it should have. If the problem goes away after artificially increasing the `LoadCount`, meaning that you've confirmed your theory, you'll have to take a different approach to debugging it -- figuring out when and why it got unloaded.

Answer (score 3):

A dll that is linked while compiling will normally have a LoadCount of -1 (0xffff) and it is not Unloadable Via FreeLibrary

so you can utilize the loadModule Event to break on a Dynamically Loaded Module and increase the LoadCount during the Event

**Blink of InLoadOrderModuleList (last dll Loaded in the process)** when on initial break at ntdll!Dbgbreak() xp-sp3 for an arbitrary console app which uses a dll

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY FullDllName LoadCount @@((( @$peb)->Ldr)->InLoadOrderModuleList.Blink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll"
   +0x038 LoadCount   : 0xffff  <----------- not unloadable via FreeLibrary
```

**setting up break on Specific Module Load**

```
0:000> sxe ld skeleton
0:000> g
ModLoad: 10000000 10005000   C:\skeleton.dll
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c90e514 c3              ret
```

the LoadModule Breaks on MapSection so Ldr isnt yet updated

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY FullDllName LoadCount @@((( @$peb)->Ldr)->InLoadOrderModuleList.Blink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll"
   +0x038 LoadCount   : 0xffff
```

**go up until the Ldr is updated**

```
0:000> gu;gu;gu

ntdll!LdrpLoadDll+0x1e9:
7c91626a 8985c4fdffff    mov     dword ptr [ebp-23Ch],eax ss:0023:0013fa3c=00000000
```

**blink  showing the last loaded Module notice loadCount 0 not updated yet**

```
0:000> dt ntdll!_LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY FullDllName LoadCount @@((( @$peb)->Ldr)->InLoadOrderModuleList.Blink)
   +0x024 FullDllName : _UNICODE_STRING "C:\skeleton.dll"
   +0x038 LoadCount   : 0
```

**dump the LoadEntry of the module**

```
0:000> !dlls -c skeleton
Dump dll containing 0x10000000:

**0x00252840:** C:\skeleton.dll
      Base   0x10000000  EntryPoint  0x10001000  Size        0x00005000
      Flags  0x00000004  LoadCount   0x00000000  TlsIndex    0x00000000
             LDRP_IMAGE_DLL
```

increase load count arbitrarily and redump  (process attach hasnt been called yet)

```
0:000> ed 0x252840+0x38  4
0:000> !dlls -c skeleton
Dump dll containing 0x10000000:

0x00252840: C:\skeleton.dll
      Base   0x10000000  EntryPoint  0x10001000  Size        0x00005000
      Flags  0x00000004  LoadCount   0x00000004  TlsIndex    0x00000000
             LDRP_IMAGE_DLL
```

run the binary

0:000> g

dll is loaded into the process break with ctrl+break

Break-in sent, waiting 30 seconds...
(aa0.77c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)

ntdll!DbgBreakPoint:
7c90120e cc              int     3

dump and see system has updated the loadcount to our count+1 also process attach has been called

```
0:001> !dlls -c skeleton
Dump dll containing 0x10000000:

0x00252840: C:\skeleton.dll
      Base   0x10000000  EntryPoint  0x10001000  Size        0x00005000
      Flags  0x80084004  LoadCount   0x00000005  TlsIndex    0x00000000
             LDRP_IMAGE_DLL
             LDRP_ENTRY_PROCESSED
             LDRP_PROCESS_ATTACH_CALLED
```

btw `use ken johnsons (skywing)` `sdbgext !remotecall` instead of .call 
it doesnt require Private Symbols

.load sdbgext 
!remotecall kernel32!LoadLibraryA 0 "c:\skeleton.dll" ; g

should load the dll in the process

or use

```
    !loaddll "c:\\skeleton.dll" from the same extension     
kernel32!LoadLibraryA() will be run when execution is resumed
0:002> g
kernel32!LoadLibraryA() [conv=0 argc=4 argv=00AC0488]
kernel32!LoadLibraryA() returned 10000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way - get .dll path and LoadLibrary it.
It will increase .dll reference count and .dll will not be released.

Comment: That's what I assumed. But how do I exactly do it in WinDbg? Note, that this is not C++ code.

Comment: Then it's more complex. You could use remote injecting technique to put newly compiled c++ dll into process where you want to keep it, and from that process to load your dll which you want to lock.

I think simplest code snipet which I could propose:

https://sourceforge.net/p/diagnostic/svn/HEAD/tree/Tools/msgboxSupress/

But of course it contains huge amount of stuff that you don't need.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586680/is-it-possible-to-suppress-messagebox-when-running-a-specific-command/40751656#40751656

Comment: In same svn there is also memory leak detection tool - but it's more complex to change.

Comment: Btw - it's possible to manually alter pinning count on dll, after your dll injection - but it might have it's own risks. FYI:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463670/dll-loadcount-on-windows-8/40792175#40792175