# Is it possible to suppress MessageBox when running a specific command?

Tags: c++, batch-file, svn

I'm using Tortoise SVN, and TortoisePlink for remote ssh connections.
From time to time TortoisePlink is displaying errors like:

```
---------------------------
TortoisePlink Fatal Error
---------------------------
Network error: Software caused connection abort
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

And they appears as messagebox and needs to be clicked by end-user.

I have tried to suppress messagebox by using -batch from command line, but problem still can be reproduced. For me it's sufficient if I'll disable messagebox prompting and print for example in command line same information - since my batch will retry later on again automatically.

Does there exists such software which can override default windows behavior and print in console window whatever is displayed in message box.

I guess in simplest terms such command line tool can be easily created, using for example

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra

and override MessageBoxA / MessageBoxW - but have anyone done this kind of thing ?

Comment: If you feel lucky you could change the [TortoisePlink code](https://sourceforge.net/p/tortoisesvn/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/ext/TortoisePlink/) directly.

Comment: Ah, did not know where that code is. Let me check later on. Thank BTW !

Comment: But of course it requires some dependencies on windows, does not compile out of box.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to suppress the dialog boxes that TortoisePlink is showing, use the [original Plink](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/). TortoisePlink is a fork of Plink to explicitly show message boxes and *not* print anything on a command line, because it's designed for an UI app and not for console apps.

And if you really only want to use svn from a batch file, don't use TortoiseSVN but the original svn command line client (can be installed with the TSVN installer as well) and use the 'svn' command from the command line.

Comment: I use Tortoise SVN for automatic svn updates - so I need to use it as a batch. And yes, I use svn command for that purpose. But additionally to this, I use also TortoisePLink for supporting svn+ssh:// protocol.

Comment: use 'svn up /path/to/workingcopy' instead. TortoiseSVN is an UI client and it not intended for batch processing. And then configure Plink instead of TortoisePlink to be used.

Comment: To my best understanding it's meant to be used for batch processing - there even exists -batch command line argument for it. But where do I get Plink.exe instead for windows ?

Comment: You *can* use it for batch processing, but then you must expect UI/dialogs to show up. The command line switches in TSVN are meant to be used to automate the UI, not for completely unattended use.

Comment: And the link to Plink on Windows is in my original answer.

Comment: Did not find any PLink link - where that one is ?

Comment: One click on the download page which gets you here : http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html and then there's plink.

Comment: So, what I understand from this is that there is no way to use both Plink and TortoiseSVN for different purposes on the same machine? My only option at this point is to repeatedly uninstall and reinstall TortoiseSVN? There must be a better way. I just want to disable TortoisePlink temporarily.

Comment: Actually, it was simple.  I changed my environment variable GIT_SSH to point to plink instead of tortoisePlink

Answer (score -1):

TortoisePLink.exe is targetted for end-user - so it's intended to display message boxes, however - there also exists a command line version of PLink.exe, and it can be downloaded from here:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Please notice that "TortoiseSVN" > "Settings" > "Network" > "SSH Client" should use TortoisePLink.exe - errors will be displayed to end-user.

For following file however -

```
%appdata%\Subversion\
file ‘config’:
In section [tunnels]
Add line like this:
ssh = Plink.exe  -l <your login> -pw <password>
```

You should use command line version of PLink.exe (that is also displaying command prompt when launched).

It's easier to save PLink.exe next with TortoisePLink.exe, that is into 
`C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin`.

I have tried to make a command line tool for supressing messageboxes, but it's useless for TortoisePLink.exe (Haven't debugged what is the problem), but in case if you're interested (Have other means to use it):

https://sourceforge.net/p/diagnostic/svn/HEAD/tree/Tools/msgboxSupress/

msSupress.cpp is compiled into .dll and it uses minimalistic hook for windows to disable MessageBoxA and MessageBoxW - actually they will be printed to console or redirected to file.

msSupressExe.cpp is compiled into .exe and it starts process in suspended mode, replaces .exe's entry point with EB FE (jump short into itself), waits until that address is reached, injects .dll and .dll will hook new process.

I have tested only on 64-bit platform - I suspect that command being executed must match same platform as as msSupress.exe.

So typically TortoisePlink.exe will display messagebox - but when executed like this:

```
mbSupress.exe "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe"
```

Same stuff as shown over message box will be displayed in console.

I think this solution is good prototype for further virus or trojan construction - using technique like this will allow to intercept even keyboard presses on any application - but I now made a command line utility, not a virus.