# Why use ReadProcessMemory() with handle to current process?

Tags: c++, windows, readprocessmemory

Using [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx), one can obtain the current process base address by reading the PebBaseAddress field in the returned struct of type PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.

I've seen code that uses [ReadProcessMemory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) to read memory with respect to the base address of the current process, as the first few bytes contain some pointers that reveal detailed process information. I also needed to obtain some of this information, and [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463670/dll-loadcount-on-windows-8) showed me how to do so.

I'm still confused, however, as to why [ReadProcessMemory()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) is required when reading memory from the current process. Can't the pointer relative to process base just be dereferenced, or will/may it result in a segmentation fault? Are pointers held with respect to the process base?

Comment: It is not required.  Very easy to verify by just trying it.

Comment: ReadProcessMemory is widely used for reading the memory of other processes. In your case you can use pointers

Comment: @HansPassant Simply trying it does not guarantee that it will be successful in all possible instances, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReadProcessMemory` will check for you that the address range in your own process is valid and return error (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY) in the case of problem instead of crashing.

Other than that I see no reason. If you are sure that your pointer is correct, it is fine (and way faster) to use `memcpy`.